# Url slug but the end not

Tags: regex

This preg_replace makes url with - for example from string example text here:

```
http://example.com/example-text-here
```

but if string have a something like example(text)is(here) it slug like:

```
http://example.com/example-text-here- 

   $url = preg_replace("![^a-z0-9]+!i", "-", strtolower(htmlspecialchars(@$_POST["name"])));
```

at the end I don't know to have -

Comment: Or `$url = preg_replace_callback("/([^a-z0-9]+)$|[^a-z0-9]+/i", function ($m) { return isset($m[1]) ? "" : "-";}, $str);`

Comment: @Robbit Averill Can remove at the end or in center too ?

Comment: Yes both works.Thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a capturing group around one of the values and use an alternation group. Then, check the group inside a `preg_replace_callback` callback:

```
$url = preg_replace_callback("/([^a-z0-9]+)$|[^a-z0-9]+/i", function ($m) { 
          return isset($m[1]) ? "" : "-";
       }, $str);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/TvaOyY)

*Regex explanation*:

- `([^a-z0-9]+)$` - Group 1 matching 1 or more characters other than letter and digits up to the end of string
- `|` - or...
- `[^a-z0-9]+` - 1 or more characters other than letter and digits

With `isset` we check if the first group matched, and if yes, we replace with nothing, else, replace with `-`.

However, perhaps, [Robbie's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888391/url-slug-but-the-end-not/34888733#comment57515352_34888391) using a second step with `$url = trim($url, '-')` is more readable. See [`trim` help](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.trim.php):

> Strip whitespace (or other characters) ***from the beginning and end of a string***